# I want to see the summary of a regression model

Tags: python

```py
independent_variables = df_raw.iloc[:,2:9] 
dependent_variable = df_raw.loc[:,"PUMP FAILURE (1 or 0)"] independent_variables = sm.add_constant(independent_variables) 
regression_model = sm.OLS(dependent_variable,independent_variables) 
regression_model.summary
```

Comment: What exactly do you want? What does that code output?

Comment: Got if figured out, using this code                                               
independent_variables = df_stdev.iloc[:,2:9]
dependent_variable = df_stdev.loc[:,"PUMP FAILURE (1 or 0)"]
independent_variables = sm.add_constant(independent_variables)
regression_model = sm.OLS(dependent_variable,independent_variables).fit()
regression_model.summary()                                                                             
Thanks a lot.